# How to make use of test cache in Gradle managed devices - Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation, gradle-managed-device

```
Main App --> Test App
   |                |
   |                ---> Test1 for feature1, Test2 for feature2
   ---> feature 1(compose screen)    
   |
   |
   ---> feature 2(compose screen)
```

This is my app architecture. Changing in feature1 should only run Test1, but Gradle Managed Devices runs all the tests every time.

Test1 has no traces of feature2 and Test2 has no traces of feature1 here.

How do I properly modularize my tests to make use of Test cache in Gradle managed devices?